# OpenFileDialog not returning to code Windows Form

Tags: c#, windows, windows-forms-designer, openfiledialog

I've been developing an app in Windows Froms to select multiple visual studio sln files and add them to a list. The app works great in two machines, but it just get freeze in other two. We had making some research if the issue was with the paths in the system but all the paths are the same. Finally, we decide to develop "again" the app in the machine that doesn't work, and we notice that the issue appears when we open the file dialog, it never returns to code.

```
private void AddService_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog fileDial = new OpenFileDialog();
        fileDial.InitialDirectory = textPath.Text;
        fileDial.Filter = "Sln(*.sln)|*.sln";
        fileDial.FilterIndex = 1;
        fileDial.Multiselect = true;

        if (fileDial.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)//Never returns to test the condition.
        { //Add to list here} 
    }
```

First we think that was and memory issue, but the memory usage in the system is very low, and the app running has a memory usage of 26,7 MB. Our app.config file is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/></startup></configuration>
```

Our develop and target system is Windows Server 2012. The system where the app runs good was two Windows Server 2012 that are clones of the machine where the app doesn't work, made them with sysprep.

Comment: Does the same dialog in other applications work? Like Notepad, or a minimal application just containing an OpenFileDialog?

Comment: did you run the app with administrator privilege?
Create "Application Manifest File" and add this line into manifest
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />

Comment: The FileDialog works with other apps. I execute the app with Administrator privilege and the issue it's the same. It seems to use some CPU, rising till 20% ​​of usage when it freezes.

Comment: It's seem to be because of an unhandler exception in one of the dll files. If the app acquire a big cuantity of threads started by the dll, the OpenFileDialog freezes the app. With a little number of threads started by the dll, the app works. We are going to investigate the issue.